# Is it OK to call $O(N^2\log N)$ as a quasi-quadratic time complexity?

Tags: notation, terminology, computational-complexity

I was just looking at some big $O$ time complexity notations given by [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Sub-quadratic_time) and I can say that $O(N\log N)$ has a quasi-linear time complexity, whereas $O(N)$ is obviously linear.

What I can say for sure is that $O(N^2\log N)$ is super-quadratic and sub-cubic.. but it is a long definition..

> Would it be okay to generalize this calling $O(N^2\log N)$ as quasi-quadratic and similarly $N^3\log N$ as quasi-cubic? Please provide some references if its okay.

Comment: You can call it whatever you want, provided that you define your terms, first.  That being said, it looks to me like a [quasi-quadratic map](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=quasi-quadratic) typically means one that is of order $O(n^{2+o(1)})$, which is a slightly different definition.  You could also call it "log-quadratic", I suppose.